# Не удается подключить драйвер SQL

Tags: mysql, драйвер

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class CheckDB {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb"; // Имя базы данных
        String username = "root"; // Ваше имя пользователя
        String password = "зфііцщкв"; // Ваш пароль

        try {
            // Загрузка драйвера для MySQL
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

            // Установка соединения с базой данных
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, username, password);

            System.out.println("Подключено к базе данных.");

            // Закрытие соединения
            connection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Исключение, возникающее, если база данных не существует
            System.out.println("База данных не существует. Создание...");

            try {
                // Установка соединения с MySQL без указания базы данных
                Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/", username, password);

                // Создание базы данных
                Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                statement.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE mydb");

                System.out.println("База данных 'mydb' успешно создана.");

                // Закрытие соединения
                connection.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Выдает ошибку: Database does not exist. Creating it...
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
Никакие методы решения не помогают. Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить